# Add Site Module Error : Unrecognized GUID Format

Tags: sxa, module

I'm using Sitecore 9.1 and SXA 1.8

I added a new module, let's call it "Test Module",and I cloned its contents from SXA's "Link List" Component, However when i try to add this module to a site using "Add Site Module" I consistently get the error

```
ManagedPoolThread #10 14:09:59 ERROR An error occured while processing /sitecore/system/Settings/Feature/TestModule/TestModuleSite Setup/Add Available Renderings action
ManagedPoolThread #10 14:09:59 ERROR Unrecognized Guid format. Actual value:
```

I'm not sure what the problem here is, i tried checking all the items and linked items at the mentioned error path but they all exist, when i search with their IDs they come up just fine.. any hints as to what the problem might be or what steps I can do to fix it would be appreciated.